# Post drop down value of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin, shopping-cart

I have an html table created dynmically  in PHP.The table has checkbox,Name Price and quantity.The quantity is dropdown list.I want to know how to post all these values depending on selected checkbox.Here is small snipet.What I want is the user will select 
checkbox and i want to post name,price and selected quantity to another page cart.php.

What i am having working right now is i am only able  to post selected checkbox value by doing $_POST["checkboxes"].But i dont know to post value for those selected checkboxes.Please help..I am trying to learn PHP.

```
<form action="cart.php" name="myform" id="menuform" method="post" >
echo "<label>"."Appetizers"."</label>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<table class='appetizerstable'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Select";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Name";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Price";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "quantity";
echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($appetizers)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" ."<input type='checkbox' name ='checkboxes[]'  value=".$row['id'].">".
             "</td>";
echo "<td>" ."<label name='foodname[]'>". $row['name']."</label>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" ."<label name='foodprice[]'>". $row['price']."</label>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>"."<select id='quantity[] name='quantity[]'>".
"<option value='1'>1</option>".
"<option value='1'>2</option>".
"</select>".
"</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<center>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need to send the name and price values as you can always retrieve those from the database by knowing the id of that item when sending the form data. So we will be focusing on just the `quantities` and the `id` of the items checked.

The main problem with what you are trying to do is that the `quantity[]` form data and the `checkboxes[]` form data wont have the same amount of items in the array when the form is sent....unless you check off every item. What happens is `checkboxes` only gets data sent when the box is checked while `quantity[]` gets data sent when a select option is selected and by default one is always selected. So basically every quantity select data will get sent whether its checked or not. So it will be hard to determine which quantity array items belong to the checkboxes array items. But there is a solution....a complicated one but still a solution with just php.

**Here is the new HTML**
*I cleaned it up a bit for readability*

```
<form action="cart.php" name="myform" id="menuform" method="post" >
    <label>Appetizers</label>
    <center>
        <table class="appetizerstable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($appetizers)) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name ="checkboxes[]"  value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label><?php echo $row['name']; ?></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label><?php echo $row['price']; ?></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="quantity[]" name="quantity[]">
                            <option value="<?php echo '1-' . $row['id']; ?>">1</option>
                            <option value="<?php echo '2-' . $row['id']; ?>">2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    <center>
</form>
```

Ok so what changed...well take a look at the new `quantity[]` values. I have appended a dash followed by the row id. Now each value has a unique value and we have a way to associate the quantity value with the check box value. We will figure this out on the cart.php file next. Here is how to do that:

**cart.php**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['checkboxes']) && isset($_POST['quantity']) ) {
    $checkboxes = $_POST['checkboxes'];
    $quantities_unfiltered = $_POST['quantity'];

    $quantities = array();

    foreach($quantities_unfiltered as $unfiltered) {

        $filtered = explode('-', $unfiltered);
        // $filtered now equals a 2 item array
        // $flitered[0] = the quantity value
        // $filtered[1] = the id

        // create an associative array for easy access to the quantity by using the id as the array key

        $quantities[ $filtered[1] ] = $filtered[0];

    }

    // now we can figure out the quantity values for each checkbox checked
    // test it out by echoing the values

    foreach($checkboxes as $id) {
        echo 'Item with id of ' . $id . ' was selected with a quantity of ' . $quantities[$id] . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Hope that helps you out a bit.

**UPDATE**

I added an if statement in the cart.php example and removed the `foodprice[]` and `foodname[]` from the name attributes as they don't send as POST data anyways as the html is not a form element. I got a little picky about that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery to submit form when change on dropdown value

> `<select name="" id="" onchange="this.form.submit()">
>   ..........
>   .........
>   </select>`